# When do we need to use `sw_sanitize`?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, html-sanitizing

Sanitizing user input is important to prevent potential security vulnerabilities such as cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. In Shopware 6 there's a filter `sw_sanitize` for that. In the templates they mostly use it for translated snippets like [detail.productNumberLabel](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/7ae7dbe1963004bf798704ddf9d785ad289c5f30/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig#L197). When digging in the templates one can see that for a lot of entity properties, sanitizing is skipped, for example with [page.product.translated.name](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/7ae7dbe1963004bf798704ddf9d785ad289c5f30/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/headline.html.twig#L7). What's the thinking about this? IMO these values should also be sanitized but maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product name is of type `StringField`, as you can see in the [ProductTranslationDefinition](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.5.3.1/src/Core/Content/Product/Aggregate/ProductTranslation/ProductTranslationDefinition.php#L57). Those fields are sanitized automatically within the [StringFieldSerializer](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.5.3.1/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/FieldSerializer/StringFieldSerializer.php#L62), which is calling the `sanitize` method of the [AbstractFieldSerializer](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.5.3.1/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/FieldSerializer/AbstractFieldSerializer.php#L164).

The "productNumberLabel" on the other side is a snippet which could be overwritten by the merchant. So it needs to be made sure, that it is sanitized correctly, while it is displayed.

Comment: Maybe this explanation should be added on https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/storefront-reference/twig-function-reference#filter?

Comment: feel free to create a PR for that :-) 

https://github.com/shopware/docs/blob/master/resources/references/storefront-reference/twig-function-reference.md

Comment: So there are two security layers, right? But if auto escaping is on anyways, this part would not necessary be needed? Anyways "doppelt hält besser" :-)

Comment: The docs are updated :-)

Answer (score 2):

One should only use `sw_sanitize` when basic html tags *are allowed* to be displayed, like `<b>`,`<i>`,...
By default, `autoescaping` is on in TWIG so all values are escaped. This is stated in the docs https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#html-escaping

> When generating HTML from templates, there's always a risk that a variable will include characters that affect the resulting HTML. There are two approaches: manually escaping each variable or automatically escaping everything by default.
>
> Twig supports both, automatic escaping is enabled by default.